# Where can I pass the Id_token using openid connect

Tags: angular, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

Using the implicit flow my response_type can be "id_token token" or "id_token", both tokens are then saved on the client.

I know what to do with the access_token on the client:

- To call the user profile endpoint you use the access_token.
- To call the Api/Resource server you use the access_token

Where should/can I pass the id_token to get what?

Comment: You should use https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor take a look at https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors

Comment: Thats not an answer to my question nor it is related. Its just advertisement for an ebook... I am asking about the purpose of the id_token and its further handling after it is stored on client side!

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to pass the token anywhere, it should contain the user's claims.  Primarily you might be interested in the user id, but the claims can be just about anything.  Once you verify and decode the token (which is JWT) you should be able to read this info and act accordingly.  See this link for more info on ID tokens: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-token